# Asp.net call iframe __doPostBack before parent Submit in chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, iframe

I have a parent page Page.aspx with input type submit button what i need is to before sumbit return true i need to call its iframe __PostBack.
in IE it is working quit fine but in chrome it is not firing iFrame __PostBack.
here is my code:
**PageA.aspx**

```
<input type="submit" id="btnNext" class="buttons" onclick="return SubmitForm('uwtNav');">

function SubmitForm(ctlName){
window.frames[iframe.id].SubmitForm();
return true;}
```

**PageB.aspx(iFrame)**

```
function SubmitForm()
    {
        try
        {
            __doPostBack('', 'MyCustomArgument_0');
        }
        catch(error){}
    }
```

Here __doPostBack for Iframe is not being fired.

Thanks